# additional user account

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

Hello  I have a toshiba satellite series laptop running dual boot OS's Windos7 and Ubuntu. Everything is well as far as I can tell but all of a sudden when I boot into Windows I am seeing the option of opening a different account ie. (Guest account)  I have never opened a guest account and upon checking the guest account is turned off. I tried to open this "mystery" account but it is password protected. Any thoughts on this weirdness?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that someone installed a second user account and named it Guest. Or some software (or virus) did this automatically. I'm guessing you have admin access on the machine. Check if the Guest account that is on the computer is the same as the Guest account that is turned off. I don't think the built-in guest account can be set up with a password, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I've just checked on XP and the built in Guest account doesn't have a password.

Comment: I would think virus/trojan or someone else has gained access to your machine.

Answer (score 1):

use the **[NT Offline Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)** to remove the password from this account.

it may shed some light on the matter.